# Enabled Migrations : System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException Type is not resolved for member

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, migration

I encounter this error while continuously active migration s my problem.
Google also tried to resolve the problems. But the solutions do not solve my problem that I get.

**How can I solve this problem?**

```
PM> Enable-migrations
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type is not resolved for member 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade+GetContextTypeRunner,EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.GetContextType(String contextTypeName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.FindContextToEnable(String contextTypeName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Type is not resolved for member 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade+GetContextTypeRunner,EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> My old project path: D://Programs&Projects/Project
>
> New project path: D://ProgramsProjects/Project

Problem is solved. Remove & character fix the problem.

Comment: Exactly the problem was & character in the path of the project file.